# A word for 'excessively long'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to describe to a friend (who is trying to force "Broadchurch" on me) why it is I hate TV shows with such a passion.

One of my main reasons for being put off is that they drag on for an entire season, often comprising up to 10 hours of viewing time. Frankly, I'd rather watch Hugh Jackman's and Jake Gyllenhall's "Prisoners" which gives me the same thrill- ride in much less time.

One word that occurred to me was `protracted`, but I'm not entirely sure if that fits here, especially since it means `lasting longer than expected`, whereas a TV show lasts as long as it is meant to.

Comment: Maybe 'interminable' https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=interminable+definition

Comment: I think your explanation here -- especially the verb phrase "drag on for an entire season" -- is much better than any single adjective would be.

Comment: Two words, "ad" and "infinitum," two Latin words for "to infinity" might be of help. Series TV shows continue ad infinitum. Also, @ruakh has a good expression: drag on. When combined with my suggestion you have "Series TV shows drag on ad infinitum." Your friend may just be impressed with your Latin phrase. Don

Comment: @rhetorician: I can't take credit for "drag on"; the OP used it in his post.

Comment: Simply "endless" or "never ending". Also "long-winded".

Comment: If it's just a long word it's "sesquipedalian", but that doesn't quite do justice to a long TV show.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I relate to your feelings for a film that does not interest you, seems too time-consuming and liked by a friend who cannot be persuaded otherwise. With that said, I personally think of something like "tedious", which may suggest some of the disdain you feel.

Other words: prolonged, laborious, time-consuming.

Comment: I think tedious fits well in my case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider **drawn-out** or **long-drawn-out**

> : extended to a great length [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/long-drawn-out)
>
> *A long-drawn-out story.*